# Add the string from the loop in the ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm parsing a jsonData and getting the video_url from it. What my requirements is to add the video_url inside the ArrayList. I've tried everything and getting the result as this in my logCat :

```
E/VIDEO URL: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhovi-android.appspot.com/o/MySavedVideo%2FJIMyHoviVideo.mp4?alt=media&token=c103543e-31f0-4682-9b44-09d679c76699]
E/VIDEO URL: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhovi-android.appspot.com/o/MySavedVideo%2FBMMyHoviVideo.mp4?alt=media&token=9bcf98a1-dad1-4f63-864f-7559ef1d49c1]
```

Now here you can clearly see that the video_url is coming in this format what I want a single ArrayList containing both the url.

This is the code I've done to print the desired result but it is not coming fine :

```
private void jsonParsingVideoData(String projectVideos, String projectId) throws JSONException{

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(projectVideos);

        ArrayList<String> video_url = null;
        for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length() ; i++){
            JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            video_url = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jObject.getString("video_url")));
            Log.e("VIDEO URL", video_url.toString());
        }
 }
```

I've tried in this way also but it failed, only one output is there if I'm doing in this way out of the loop.

```
for( String string : video_url){
   ArrayList<String> string1 = new ArrayList<>();
   string.add(string);
   Log.e("LOGS", string1.toString());
}
```

for the above code the output is coming only one and in this format :

```
E/LOGS: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhovi-android.appspot.com/o/MySavedVideo%2FBMMyHoviVideo.mp4?alt=media&token=9bcf98a1-dad1-4f63-864f-7559ef1d49c1]
```

Please help me with this, I've tried a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating a new ArrayList every loop iteration. You should use `add` instead!

```
private void jsonParsingVideoData(String projectVideos, String projectId) throws JSONException{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(projectVideos);

    ArrayList<String> video_urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        video_urls.add(jObject.getString("video_url"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked, I don't know why I got downvoted, it was just a mistake you helped in a great way. Thank I learned from it. Will accept your answer too in a bit.